# Passing `init-param` to servlet from Guice not working

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, guice, jersey-2.0

Trying to pass initialization parameters to my servlet using Guice ([MyServletModule.java](http://pastebin.com/cw7gxn84)):

```
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("key1", "value1");
    params.put("key2", "value2");
    this.serve("/hi").with(HelloWorldServlet.class, params);
```

and then trying to print it out in my servlet:

```
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    resp.getWriter().println("Hello, my singleton AppEngine");

    resp.getWriter().println("key1: " + this.getServletContext().getInitParameter("key1"));
```

and I always get a `null`. What am I doing wrong? I suspect my integration of Guice **and** Jersey with GAE is at fault, but can't troubleshoot it.

Files:

- [MyServletModule.java](http://pastebin.com/cw7gxn84)
- [MyContextListener.java](http://pastebin.com/c8zLqk7r)
- [MyModule.java](http://pastebin.com/VzLA7qdV)
- [JerseyConfiguration.java](http://pastebin.com/0GrC3cQi)
- [JerseyFilter.java](http://pastebin.com/hyV1EFmF)
- [web.xml](http://pastebin.com/2jfkdjJi)

Configuration:

- Google App Engine for Java 1.9.26
- Guice 4.0
- Jersey 2.5.1
- Objectify 5.1.7

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following to the servlet worked:

```
private String key1 = null;

private String key2 = null;


@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    this.key1 = config.getInitParameter("key1");
    this.key2 = config.getInitParameter("key2");
}
```

and then in the `doGet(...)` method:

```
    resp.getWriter().println("key1: " + this.key1);
    resp.getWriter().println("key2: " + this.key2);
```